# git: how to merge or rebase after a rebase?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I made the mistake of doing a rebase to merge my branch with the latest version of the branch it was based on.  I say mistake because I didn't realise it would be more difficult later (e.g. git pull causes major conflicts where there should be none, and git push needs force).

This is what I did so far:

```
$ git checkout major_branch
$ git pull
$ git checkout my_branch
make some changes and commits.
$ git rebase major_branch
make some changes and commits.
$ git push --force
```

Now I need to get the latest changes from major_branch (again).  Noone but me has worked on my_branch.

How would I do this without catastrophe?

I.e. Can I rebase more than once?

Can I go back to merging and abandon rebasing?

Is this the right way?:

```
$ git checkout major_branch 
$ git pull               // does this only pull major_branch, or all branches from origin?
$ git checkout my_branch // my_branch exists locally and on origin. what if they are different?
$ git merge major_branch // is this the correct "way round"?
$ git push --force . // push my_branch back to server in case my local machine dies.
```

If major_banch, which is my "parent" becomes obsolete, and now everyone is using "major_branch2", what are my options?  Can I simply do "git rebase major_banch2"?

At some point, I need to put my changes back into major_branch. How do I do this?  Can I do something like:

```
$ git checkout major_branch
$ git pull               // does this only pull major_branch?
$ git merge my_branch // is this the correct "way round"?
fix merge conflicts
$ git commit
$ git push // do I need to force?
```

As another option, is there a way to get out of my current rebased situation?  I.e. get to the situtation where I have my personal feature branch, with all my changes, and also all the changes from major_banch, but not rebased, so I can simply use merge, pull and push again (i.e. a "normal" workflow)?

Answer (score 1):

You can rebase as many times as you want. When you `git pull`, only the current branch is affected. So `git checkout major_branch` followed by `git pull` will fetch and then merge `major_branch` from the remote. You can then checkout `my_branch` and do `git rebase major_branch`. This is pretty much the standard way to work with private WIP branches that no one else is working on. You will always need to force push `my_branch` when doing this.

Merging `major_branch` into `my_branch` is not needed if you prefer rebasing `my_branch` and force pushing it. It is only needed if several people are working on `my_branch` and thus force pushing would be not an option.

So, if only you are working on a branch, then rebase it and and force push it whenever needed. If other people are working on the branch, then merge the main branch into it and do normal push.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks. When I want to put my changes back into major_branch (e.g. because my work is done), how do I do this safely?

Comment: @JohnLittle I prefer fast-forward merges when possible. So here, it would be `git checkout major_branch`, then `git merge --ff-only my_branch`. This will only merge your branch into the major branch if it's fast-forwardable. This kind of merge makes it look like the commits were done directly in the main branch. However, this is not always possible, for example if you merged the main branch into your branch at some point in the past. In that case, git will report an error. You would then need to do a normal merge (`git merge my_branch`.)

Comment: @JohnLittle Note that both normal and fast-forward merging are safe. If you're not very familiar with git in general, always make a backup of your local git repo before doing anything important :-)

Comment: Is there a way to get out of my rebase? i.e. get to a branch which is not rebased?

Comment: @JohnLittle Not sure what you're asking. Do you want to abort the current rebase instead of solving the conflicts? For that, you just do `git rebase --abort`. `git status` will tell you that though.

Comment: No, I have a rebased branch, with all my commits.  however, I cant do a git push, I have to do git push --force, and I have a bunch of other issues. I just want to get back to being able to merge, and push, not rebase and push --force. Any ideas how I do this?

Comment: @JohnLittle No, that's not possible. You can merge and push in the future though. So do your last forced push now, and in the future do merge and normal push.